# Manipulate values in Matlab cell array

Tags: matlab, vectorization, cell

Suppose I have a 3x1 cell array called `subj` that has the following elements:

```
cell 1: 300x20 double
cell 2: 300x15 double
cell 3: 300X18 double
```

I want to remove the last quarter rows from every element in each cell as follows:

```
subj{1}(length(subj{1})*0.25+1:end,:) = []
subj{2}(length(subj{2})*0.25+1:end,:) = []
subj{3}(length(subj{3})*0.25+1:end,:) = []
```

However I want to be do this in one line and can't figure out a way to do this in Matlab. I messed around with converting the cell array to  a matrix, but since there different numbers of columns, it makes it slightly more complicated. Is there a vectorized way to do this in one line? I will be applying machine learning algorithms to each element of `subj` and it would be great to have this be vectorized for later parts of my code.

Comment: I need to vectorize that. Doing so would most likely lead to slower code than a simple loop. You can use `cellfun`, but it’s implemented as a loop and usually adds overhead compared to writing your own loop. **MATLAB loops are not slow!**

Comment: So this has to be vectorized and the vectorization should include just one line? Why are you limiting your choices? What do you think you will achieve with this?

Comment: Oops. Where I said “I need to” I intended to say “No need to”.

Answer (score 0):

Better not assigning empty arrays to a matrix (actually that doesn't work) but reassign the matrix itself:

```
% loop over the cell array
for i = 1:length(subj)
   % determine the index/number of rows. Don't forget to round as MATLAB requires integers for slicing!
   idx = round( length(subj{i})*0.25 );
   % get the new matrix
   NewMat = subj{i}(1:idx,:);
   % assign new matrix to the old address, i.e. the content of the cell
   subj{i} = NewMat;
end
```

MATLAB allocates contiguous memory for matrices, so cropping it shouldn't cause much overhead. In particular not as it uses "lazy copying" and; therefore, only copies the matrix when you change any of its values.